# (Physics) Finding the angle(s) of launch which hit a target.

Tags: physics, conic-sections

Given a coordinate and the launch speed, I need to determine which pair of angle, or angle allows a hit on said coordinate. I know, let's say, the common way, which is using the following equations:

$$
x = V_ocos(\theta)t
$$
$$
y = V_osen(\theta)t - \frac{gt^2}{2}
$$

And after removing the parameter:

$$
y = tan(\theta)x - \frac{gx^2}{2{V_o}^2cos^2\theta}
$$

And solving for $tan(\theta)$:
$$
tan(\theta) = \frac{\frac{2{V_o}^2}{gx} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{2{V_o}^2}{gx})^2 - 4(\frac{gx^2+{2V_o}^2}{gx^2})}} {2}
$$

Now, that's big, plus there's too much margin for error. Do you know a better way to calculate the angle(s) of launch which hits $(x,y)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "too big"? It seems quite reasonable to me.

If you are worried about cancellation in an expression of the form
$a \pm \sqrt{a^2-b}$, use the standard technique of
computing the root with the sign of the $\sqrt{}$ having the
same sign as $a$, and then use
$(a \pm \sqrt{a^2-b})(a \mp \sqrt{a^2-b})
= a^2 - (a^2-b) = b
$
to get the other root.